# java file copying excluding the already copied files

Tags: java, file

I am trying to copy the files from one folder to another folder which is in another server, where the files in that folder are generated periodically.

At first I am copying the files that are generated in that folder and it is fine. After sometime I Want to copy the newly generated files excluding the old files.

Is there any java API to copy the newly generated files excluding the already copied files from a folder?

Comment: I don't think you'll find an API for that - it's a specialized requirement and you'll probably need to make comparisons based on modification date etc. But do you have to do this in Java? There are existing tools for this like `rsync`, and it's a shame to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

You can user [WatchService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html) to detect new files or changed files in a directory. Register like:

```
Path dir = ...;
try {
    WatchKey key = dir.register(watcher,
                           ENTRY_CREATE,
                           ENTRY_MODIFY);
} catch (IOException x) {
    System.err.println(x);
}
```

And then you can react on changes, using something like:

```
// wait for key to be signaled
WatchKey key;
try {
    key = watcher.take();
} catch (InterruptedException x) {
    return;
}
```

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html) you can find more details, also on how to establish what has changed.